# Force an object to be passed as copy to a function receiving a universal reference

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdbind

I'm trying to pass a local lambda function to a `std::bind` (for passing to a `connect` function of a signal):

```
void f()
{
    auto signal_f = [this](int, int) { /* ... */ };

    namespace ph = std::placeholders;
    signal.connect(std::bind(signal_f, ph::_1, ph::_2));
}
```

But the function parameter of `std::bind` is received as a universal reference:

```
template<class F, class... Args>
/* unspecified */ bind(F&& f, Args&&... args);
```

So, since my lambda object is a named object, it's passed as a lvalue reference , but my lambda object will be destroyed after `f()` exists, potentially causing memory leaks when the signal is emited.

What is the simplest way of passing that object by copy?

Of course, I could do always things like:

```
signal.connect(std::bind<std::decay<decltype(signal_f)>::type>
   (signal_f, ph::_1, ph::_2));
```

of other tricky ways but they are too cumbersome, so, what is the simplest way of doing it?

**NOTE**: Is there any function from the standard library to create a copy, something like `std::make_rvalue(o)` or a `std::copy` version for objects instead of for containers?

Answer (score 5):

If you read the docs for [`std::bind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) you'll see that:

> The return type of `std::bind` holds a member object of type `std::decay<F>::type` constructed from `std::forward<F>(f)`

It doesn't hold a reference to `signal_f`, it holds a copy of it. There is no dependency on the lifetime of `signal_f`. The only dependency is on the lifetime of `this`, which `signal_f` captures.

---

Note that this:

```
signal.connect(std::bind<std::decay<decltype(signal_f)>::type>(signal_f, ph::_1, ph::_2));
```

which is actually the same as this (the `decay` is pointless since the closure type isn't a reference type):

```
signal.connect(std::bind<decltype(signal_f)>(signal_f, ph::_1, ph::_2));
```

is actually the same as:

```
signal.connect(std::bind(std::move(signal_f), ph::_1, ph::_2));
```

which you could also do.

Comment: Ok, sorry. I read the documentation but I don't literally "saw" the word **object** ("holds a member **object**"). So, I thought it just had a local `typedef` to the `decay` version of the parameter.

Answer (score 4):

`bind` does not actually store a reference to the lambda.  All the parameters are either copied(if lvalue) or moved(if rvalue) into the object returned by `bind`.

This reason is why you need to use `std::ref` when passing parameters to `bind` when the callable takes its parameters by reference.